# С# Excel interop получить имена всех ячеек на листе

Tags: c#, excel

На листе есть несколько ячеек которым заданы имена. Т.е к примеру была ячейка А5, а стала "Результат_2". 
Нужно получить имена всех ячеек листа, которым присвоены имена.

на VBA это выглядит [примерно так](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/working_with_names_in_vba/), но я не могу использовать VBA

Пытаюсь получить вот так

```
foreach(Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelPattern.Worksheets)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(wSheet.Name,wSheet.Name);

    foreach(Excel.Name n in wSheet.Names){  
        treeView1.Nodes[wSheet.Name].Nodes.Add( n.Name);
    }
}
```

В итоге вместо реальных имен из листа в дерево попадает что-то совсем не то

на листе РОД10

```
выр_проц;
выр_раб_усл;
выр_реал_соб;
```

но получаю

```
РОД10!_FilterDatabase;
РОД10!Z_7C371303_C1FE_49B4_A9DD_C1D8D4863FB7_.wvu.Rows;
РОД10!Print_Area;
```

Comment: Код писали? Покажите.

Comment: @КотковЕвгений: Если вам не сложно, скопируйте код в вопрос. И скажите, что с ним не так. Не компилируется? (Какие ошибки выдаёт?) Бросает исключение? (Какое, где, какой текст?)

Comment: @КотковЕвгений: Возможно, вам нужно `wSheet.Names`, как обсуждается [здесь](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=91009).

Comment: К сожалению я не могу использовать VBA.

Comment: @КотковЕвгений: А это свойство не доступно и из C# тоже?

Comment: Если вы про  wSheet.Names то я его и использую, перебираю с помощью foreach и получаю n.Name Вот только там содержится не то что я ожидаю (не то что есть на листе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, странно вы приводите в пример код где идёт перебор `Names` для книги, а у себя почему-то используете `Names` листа. А это не одно и то же. Excel вам корректно возвращает имена листа, они все вида "ИМЯ_ЛИСТА!имя". Вам по всей видимости нужны "глобальные" (уровня книги):

```
// var workbook = ...;
foreach(var name in workbook.Names) {
    string n = name.Name;     //  имя 
    string r = name.RefersTo; //  на что ссылается имя (Лист1!$E$29)
    // ...
}
```

Вышеуказанный код вернет все имена книги, среди них будет и то что вам нужно. Чтобы связать имя ячейки с конкретным листом нужно использовать свойство `RefersTo`.